# Variable in javascript to Define as Static

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a signup and signin operation in HTML and Javascript. In that i have 2 html pages signup , signin html pages and one javascript file(accesed from two pages). If i add user from Sign up page how i can access that variable from the signin page.

I think that if i declare a variable(or array,objects) by accessing from other page can check for the signin activity.

javascript

```
var usrlist=[];
function sign_up()
{
    var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    usrlist.push(uname);
    usrlist.push(pas);
}


function sign_in()
{
    var usrname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var pass=document.getElementById("pass").value;
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=usrlist[0]+"<br>pass"+usrlist[1];
}
```

console.log(usrlist) for signup activity have value but in signin activity it will be null how can i make the variable available or array available for both of them.

please help..Thanks

Comment: At the time of page refresh .javascript was reloaded.so the value will be null better use php session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `window.localStorage.setItem(key, value)` on one page and `window.localStorage.getItem(key)` on the other one to keep and exploit strings between pages. Sure, you can always use JSON to pass more complicated objects instead strings: `JSON.stringify(object)` and `JSON.parse(string)`.